# Sorting by Newest and Oldest First Not Working

Tags: reactjs, sorting

I am trying to sort the data from a JSON file by `Newest` and `Oldest` First but it is giving an error `Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined`, but the code is correct

And when the user selects `default`, it should show them the unsorted default data, so the way I am doing it , is it correct?

Link of the code : [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-bush-7xsgz?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Your code sandbox requires us to make changes to even display the data you are trying to sort, I suggest you make it easy for people to assist you with your problem if you would like to receive the help you are looking for.

Comment: @Phobos can you explain what's wrong with sandbox, cause i have  check it in incognito it was showing the files

Comment: It shows all of your files, it doesn't show the piece of code you are having an issue with. And another thing, we have to go and code the logic to display the list (I had to check your data file, establish which fields are available etc etc) - you should do your best to isolate the issue so that it is easy for people to assist.

Comment: okay got it , i will do it next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is in the sorting.js file, you need to `return` the array you are sorting:

```
const SortbyNewestFirst = (array) => {
  return array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return new Date(a.reviewDate) - new Date(b.reviewDate);
  });
};

const SortbyOldestFirst = (array) => {
  return array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return new Date(b.reviewDate) - new Date(a.reviewDate);
  });
};
export { SortbyNewestFirst, SortbyOldestFirst };
```

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach,

```
export default function App() {
  const [NewData, setNewData] = useState(data);

  const [SortingValue, setSortingValue] = useState("default");
  const handleSorting = (e) => {
    setSortingValue(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.value, SortingValue);
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "newestFirst":
        setNewData(SortbyNewestFirst(NewData));
        break;
      case "oldestFirst":
        setNewData(SortbyOldestFirst(NewData));
        break;
      default:
        setNewData(data);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <select onChange={handleSorting} style={{ width: "130px" }}>
        <option value="default">Default</option>
        <option value="newestFirst">Newest First</option>
        <option value="oldestFirst">Oldest First</option>
      </select>
      <ul>
        {NewData.map((v) => (
           <li key={v.id}>
            {v.countryName} - {v.reviewDate}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

Sort logic:- here you are not returning any results.

```
const SortbyNewestFirst = (array) =>
  array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return new Date(a.reviewDate) - new Date(b.reviewDate);
  });
const SortbyOldestFirst = (array) =>
  array &&
  array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return new Date(b.reviewDate) - new Date(a.reviewDate);
  });
export { SortbyNewestFirst, SortbyOldestFirst };
```

Working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-wind-suuui?file=/src/sorting.js:0-327

Comment: well your code does work but it's doing the opposite,i mean when i select `newest First` it does oldest First sorting , vice versa  and why the default option is not working ?